# Filter or Hook to catch pre-rendering of post content

Tags: filters, hooks

Is there a filter or hook that is triggered just before post content is rendered?

What I'd like to do is to apply a filter to the text content of a post just before the post text is being rendered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you not simply use `the_content` filter hook?

```
function mytheme_content_filter( $content ) {
     // Do stuff to $content, which contains the_content()
     // Then return it
     return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'mytheme_content_filter' );
```

Comment: That's simply the filter I was looking for.

Comment: Resurrecting this old thread to notice that, by using the filter, all tags get stripped. How can I keep my tags?

Comment: @CiprianPopescu I would recommend starting a new question. It sounds to me like your issue isn't necessarily related to this question or answer. Adding your own question would allow you to elaborate more on the exact nature of your issue.